# setText() not work

Tags: java, android, nullpointerexception

I have this code in Activity.java:

```
 public void scan(View view){
    EditText text = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText3);
    text.setText("asdas");
}
```

and this in Activity xml:

```
<Button
    android:id="@+id/button"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
    android:onClick="scan"
    android:text="Scane"
    android:textColor="#fff"
    android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
    tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="271dp"
    tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="8dp" />

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/editText3"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:ems="10"
    android:inputType="textPersonName"
    android:text="Name"
    tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="89dp"
    tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="165dp" />
```

When click on button the app crash with:

```
Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void 
android.widget.EditText.setText(java.lang.CharSequence)' on a null object reference
```

Why, im use Android Studio latest version??

Comment: EditText text = (EditText)view.findViewById(R.id.editText3); and also check ur edit text id in same activity or other

Answer (score 0):

seems that `findViewById` returns `null`: i.e. it does not find your edit-text for some reason.

maybe you only need to rebuild the project: `Build` - `Rebuild Project`

otherwise you have messed up something else and must post more info

Answer (score 0):

Put this Edittext intialization code in onCreate method .

```
EditText text;
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
 text = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText3);
}

public void scan(View view){
    text.setText("asdas");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your `findViewById` is returning null since it doesn't have the context.
I think you are passing `view` object for context but not using it.
Try changing

```
EditText text = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText3);
```

to

```
EditText text = (EditText) view.findViewById(R.id.editText3);
```

Answer (score 0):

In the below code, you get the related EditText object

```
EditText text = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText3);
```

Then, you called the setText() method of that object but take null object reference

```
text.setText("asdas");
```

It means that you cannot get the EditText object properly. Thus the origin of the error causes from the below line:

```
EditText text = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText3);
```

Please be sure to invoke scan() method inside the right context. Try to invoke it inside onCreate() method. If you invoke findViewById() method from a different place, be sure to invoke it from the right context.